# How to perform some action after an async function has completed executing in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, axios

I have an HOC to render protected pages and check their permissions from config service. the config service has an async function to fetch these apis.
I want to set loader to false when i've fetched the permissions array but in my code i have to reload the page once, if i dont do that the loader keeps spinning indefinetly.

```
import { Navigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { useInjection } from "inversify-react";
import ConfigService from "../Services/_configService";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { resolve } from "path";


function render(c: JSX.Element) {
  return c;
}

const ProtectedRoute = (Component: any, route: string) => {
  const currentUser: any = useSelector((state) => state);
  
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState<boolean>(true); 
  const config = useInjection(ConfigService)
 
  useEffect(() => {
    
    setTimeout(() => {
  
      if (config.Permissions && config.Permissions.length>0) {
        setIsLoading(false);
        
      }
    }, 1000);
  
    console.log(config.Permissions)
  }, [config]);
 

  if (isLoading) {
    return    <span className="indicator-progress" style={{ display: "block" }}>
   <span className="spinner-border spinner-border-sm align-middle ms-2"></span>
  </span>
  }

  return currentUser && config.Permissions && config.Permissions.includes(route)
    ? render(Component)
    : <Navigate to="/" />;
};

export default ProtectedRoute;
```

here is my service , the constructor calls the loadconfig function

```
import { injectable } from 'inversify';
import "reflect-metadata";
import {get} from "../axios/index"
import { API_ENDPOINTS } from '../axios/apiEndpoint';

interface Configuration {
  EnableForgetPassword: string;
}

interface Data {
  configuration: Configuration[];
  permissions: string[];
}

interface ConfigData {
  data: Data;
 
}

@injectable()
class ConfigService {
  private _config: ConfigData = {
    data: {
      configuration: [{ EnableForgetPassword: "False" }],
      permissions: [""]
    },
    
  }
  private _permissions: string[] = [""]
  private _configuration: any = {};
  constructor() {
    this.loadConfigData();
  }
  async loadConfigData(): Promise<void> {
    const response = await get(API_ENDPOINTS.CONFIG_URL).then((response:AxiosResponse<Data>)=>response)
    const config = response; 
    this._permissions=config.data.permissions
    this._configuration=config.data.configuration
    
}

  get Permissions():string[]
  {  
    return this._permissions;
  }
  get  Configurations():any{
   
    return this._configuration
  }
}
export default ConfigService;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have a loading state in your config class which you can change on your promise ".then" function and return it as well. Then you can use it to change your component's loading state.